# How can I ask the user for a directory to save a .csv file using the 'save as' window?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am writing a program that will create a .csv file from an input file chosen by the user, and save that .csv file to where ever the user pleases.

Here's what I have, which saves to the same directory as the project.

```
# Create 2d list to export
full_list = list(zip(a_list, b_list, c_list))

# Create .csv
myFile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(myFile)

# Write to .csv
for unit in full_list:
    writer.writerow(unit)
```

How can I have the user select a directory and file name for the output, using the 'save as' window?

I have managed the input part using tkinter `filedialog.askopenfilename()` to return the directory of the file to open. I can't get the output part working with `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`. They seem to do the same thing? Where can I feed this file path input so the .csv is saved there?

I have tried:

```
myFile = open(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(), 'output.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(myFile)
```

Everything I find online just explains how to get the 'save as' window open, not how to feed a file in to be saved.

Comment: Post the code with what you have tried on using `asksaveasfilename()` so we can help to identify why it is not working.

Comment: @acw1668 I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to. I'm asking for any kind of solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()` function to prompt the user for the file name and directory to save the CSV file

```
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk

# Create 2d list to export
full_list = list(zip(a_list, b_list, c_list))

# Prompt the user to choose a directory and file name to save the CSV file
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')

# Create the CSV file and write to it
with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    for unit in full_list:
        writer.writerow(unit)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Why do I need root = Tk() and root.withdraw()? It works fine without.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

I thought `'output.csv'` argument was just for the file name, but it can be fed the file path as well.

```
file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')
myFile = open(file_path, 'w', newline='')
```

Comment: yes you can do that as well 